# Regex guide to remove digits from string in special conditions only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am in need to remove digits from a string with PHP code. But here is the catch —

1. If digits are in the string and have space after and before them
2. If they are at the start of the string then it needs space after the digit.
3. If they are at the end of the string then it needs space before the digit.

Ex "need 4 speed" shall become "need speed"

"4 speed" shall become "speed"

"speed 4" shall become "speed"

At the same time

"4speed" shall remain as it is

"speed4" shall remain as it is

"speed2car" shall remain as it is

Currently using below code which removes all digits eventually which is not correct for a given logic

```
$clean_string = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $dirty_string );
```

Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: need 4speed shall be as it is since it does not have space after and before nor its at the beginning of the string or at the end of the string as I stated in points 1 to 3.  Answer by The fourth bird satisfied all conditions. Thank you for your effort, I really appreciated it

Comment: I think you will find that I satisfied all of your requirements as well without using a callback.  If this is untrue, please provide a string that my snippet fails on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the variants at the start and the end of the string, and capture the ones that have spaces before and after the digits.

Using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), replace the matches from the start and the end with an empty string, and replace what is captured that contains spaces before and after with a single space.

```
^\d+\h+|\h+\d+$|(\h+\d+\h+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^\d+\h+` Start of string, match 1+ digits and 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `|` Or
- `\h+\d+$` Match 1+ horizontal whitespaces, 1+ digits at the end of the string
- `|` Or
- `(\h+\d+\h+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits between 1+ horizontal whitepaces

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEiqCS/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/B8KVU)

```
$lines = [
    "need 4 speed",
    "4 speed",
    "speed 4",
    "4speed",
    "speed4",
    "speed2car"
];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $pattern = "~^\d+\h+|\h+\d+$|(\h+\d+\h+)~";
    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
        return array_key_exists(1, $matches) ? " " : "";
    }, $line) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
need speed
speed
speed
4speed
speed4
speed2car
```

Answer (score 0):

### No callback is needed.

My suggested pattern is separated into two potential matches (only one will be engaged at a time.

The first matching one or more digits followed by a space **if** the digits begin at the start of the string or are preceded by a space.

The second matching a space followed by one or more digits **if** the digits occur at the end of the string or are followed by a space.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hq9Td))

```
$lines = [
    "need 4 speed",
    "4 speed",
    "speed 4",
    "4speed",
    "speed4",
    "speed2car",
    "need 4speed",
    "need4 speed",
];

var_export(
    preg_replace("~(?<= |^)\d+ | \d+(?= |$)~", '', $lines)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'need speed',
  1 => 'speed',
  2 => 'speed',
  3 => '4speed',
  4 => 'speed4',
  5 => 'speed2car',
  6 => 'need 4speed',
  7 => 'need4 speed',
)
```